# Hashmap into database

Tags: android

I stored hashmap in database but when the items in hashmap are more than one, the last value is shown multiple times... for example in hashmap i have

bag

pen

book

but when I retrieve the values I get

book

book

book

How do I fix this?

DatabaseHandler.java

```
public void addQuote(Quote q, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> put_q_list)
{
    myDataBase=this.getWritableDatabase();
  try{

   ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

  values.put("q_customer_name", q.getCustomer_name());
  values.put("q_customer_email", q.getCustomer_email());
  values.put("q_b_street", q.getBilling_street());
  values.put("q_b_city", q.getBilling_city());
  values.put("q_b_state", q.getBilling_state());
  values.put("q_b_zipcode", q.getBilling_zipcode());
  values.put("q_b_country", q.getBilling_country());
  values.put("q_s_street", q.getShipping_street());
  values.put("q_s_city", q.getShipping_city());
  values.put("q_s_state", q.getShipping_state());
  values.put("q_s_zipcode", q.getShipping_zipcode());
  values.put("q_s_country", q.getShipping_country());
  values.put("q_day", q.getDay());
  values.put("q_month", q.getMonth());
  values.put("q_year", q.getYear());
  values.put("q_total", q.getTotal());
  values.put("q_discount", q.getTotal_discount());

  myDataBase.insert("quote",null,values);

  }catch(Exception e)
  {
      Log.e("bderror",e.toString());
      e.printStackTrace();
  }

  String selectQuery = "SELECT quote_id FROM quote WHERE q_customer_email=?";
  Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] {q.getCustomer_email()});
  int i=0;
  while(cursor.moveToNext())
    {
      i=cursor.getInt(0);
    }
  cursor.close();

  for (HashMap<String, String> map : put_q_list) {
       ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
       cv.put("quote_id", i);
       cv.put("q_item_code", map.get("item_code_final"));
       cv.put("q_item_desc", map.get("desc_final"));
       cv.put("q_item_price", map.get("item_price_final"));
       cv.put("q_item_qty", map.get("item_qty_final"));
       cv.put("q_item_tax", map.get("item_tax_final"));
       cv.put("q_item_discount", map.get("item_discount_final")); 
       myDataBase.insert("q_item", null, cv);
    }

}
```

Add.java`

```
HashMap<String, String> map_item_final = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map_item_final.put("item_code_final",autoComplete_item.getText().toString());
        map_item_final.put("desc_final", item_desc.getText().toString());
        map_item_final.put("item_price_final", String.valueOf(item_price.getText()));
        map_item_final.put("item_tax_final",String.valueOf(item_tax.getText()));
        map_item_final.put("item_discount_final",String.valueOf(item_discount.getText()));
        map_item_final.put("item_qty_final", item_qty.getText().toString());
        final_items.add(map_item_final);
```

dataBase.addQuote(q, final_items);

Retrieving....

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getQuoteItem(String quote_id) 
{
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> put_list= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    myDataBase=this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * from q_item where quote_id="+Integer.parseInt(quote_id),null);

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
while(cursor.moveToNext())
    {
               map.put("i_item_code", cursor.getString(1));
               map.put("i_item_desc", cursor.getString(2));
               map.put("i_item_price", String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(3)));
               map.put("i_item_qty", String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(4)));
               map.put("i_item_tax", String.valueOf(cursor.getFloat(5)));
               map.put("i_item_discount", String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(6)));
               put_list.add(map);
    }
 cursor.close();
 return put_list;

}
```

SQLite database browser

The first items is becoming null!!! Only last item is stored
[img]
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8fPYT_K7J81OXl0ejFiZlpFRDQ/edit?usp=sharing

Please HELP!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is this bit of code in add quote():

```
int i=0; 
while(cursor.moveToNext()) { 
    i=cursor.getInt(0); 
}
```

You're storing the value in the cursor into an int, then overwriting it each time before you do anything with it.

Comment: Its not replacing but coming multiple times

Comment: eg: in listview its
bag
book
pen
then while retrieving
pen
pen
pen

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, bit this looks to me to be the issue. All this while loop is going to do is set i to the last id in the cursor's result set. Then in your for loop below you're inserting each value in your hashmap with the same quote_id (i).

Comment: I need the same quote id multiple times but different values in other columns

Comment: Ah, i see - sorry, think i was thrown by the while loop. (There's a cursor.moveToLast method you could use instead). I'm a bit stumped now though. Have you tried viewing the SQLite database, to see if the values are inserted correctly? This could help narrow down where the issue is occurring (inserting or fetching).

Comment: I've inserted an image above
The first items are becoming null
Only the last item is inserted

Comment: Regarding your comment in the other answer: You don't "get debug code", you "debug your code" - as in set breakpoints and step through your code, inspecting values to see where the issue is occurring. If you don't know how to do this, you really need to stop what you are doing and look it up now. Writing code without being able to debug it is like driving with your eyes closed.

Answer (score 0):

create `hashmap` object inside of `while` loop

```
HashMap<String, String> map = null;
while(cursor.moveToNext())
{
     map = new HashMap<String, String>();
     map.put("i_item_code", cursor.getString(1));
     map.put("i_item_desc", cursor.getString(2));
     map.put("i_item_price", String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(3)));
     map.put("i_item_qty", String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(4)));
     map.put("i_item_tax", String.valueOf(cursor.getFloat(5)));
     map.put("i_item_discount", String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(6)));
     put_list.add(map);
}
```

Comment: I discovered that the problem is in insertion.
you can look the image above
Only the last item is stored while previous ones are null

Comment: Image link is working! there is also a download button on the left

Comment: I need help on adding hashmap to database i.e the first code!

Comment: fixed the adding to database problem
the problem is on retrieving
tried your code still same result